# Change which python.exe to be used in bash script

Tags: python, windows, bash

Assume that `python` refers to `C:\Program\python.exe` as standard and I have a program which should be run with `C:\Program\python_2.exe`.
If I do

```sh
#!/bin/bash/
python=C:\Program\python_2.exe
python -c "print('Hello world!')" >log.txt 2>&1
```

it still uses the standard python and not `python_2`

Comment: not really related, but you probably should consider upgrading your project to python3 instead (python2 has reached EOL at the beginning of 2020)

Comment: It isn't a python 2, it is just the python in my virtual environment ("a second python interpreter")

Comment: But agreed, bad formulation of the question from my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, let's check what your script actually does:

the first line, assigns a value `C:\Program\python_2.exe` to a variable named `python`:

```sh
python=C:\Program\python_2.exe
```

however, the next line doesn't use this variable at all.
it will simply run a program `python`:

```sh
python -c "print('Hello world!')" >log.txt 2>&1
```

funnily the program has the same name as one of the many variables, but that doesn't really matter.
for the shell, variables are totally unrelated to program-names (which are literals, searched for in `${PATH}`).

if you want to use a variable for the program, you must make this explicit:

```sh
${python} -c "print('Hello world!')" >log.txt 2>&1
```

(

this still might not work, as backslashes on un*x systems (and `bash` comes from that realm) are considered special, so the `${python}` variable might not actually hold what you think it does:

```sh
$ echo ${python}
C:Programpython_2.exe
```

so you probably need to escape the backslashes:

```sh
python="C:\\Program\\python_2.exe"
```

)

if you don't want to use a variable for calling your program but the *literal* `python`, you could define a **function**:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# this defines a *shell-function* named `python`, which can be used as if it were a program:
python() {
 # call a program (python_2.exe) with all the arguments that were given to the function:
 C:\\Program\\python_2.exe "$@"
}
# call the 'python' function with some args:
python -c "print('Hello world!')" >log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Nice tpouch on the function!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use scl enable, to enable python version 2.7:

```
cd /var/www/python/scripts/
scl enable python27 "python runAllUpserts.py >/dev/null 2>&1"
```

Then you can use :

```
python -V
```